# Custom objects with HessianKit and java backend

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, hessian

I have an iPhone app that uses HessianKit to talk to my java server.  A couple of the methods I use return custom objects, and I haven't been able to figure out how to make them load as the correct object on the iPhone side.

Here is basically what I have:

in java:

```
public class QRSet implements Serializable{
{

  protected Pagination pagination;//another custom class
  protected int resultSetSize;
  protected List results;

  //...standard getters, setters, and constructors...
}
```

In objective-c

```
@protocol QRSet <NSObject>

@property (strong, atomic) id<Pagination> pagination;
@property int resultSetSize;
@property (strong, atomic) NSArray * results;

//...not sure how I would need to do getters and setters here...


@end
```

Originally I had the objective c version as its own class instead of a protocol, but I found there had been a change in how the mapping method works and now it requires this format:

```
[CWHessianArchiver setClassName:@"com.test.queries.QRSet" forProtocol:@protocol(QRSet)];
```

This is how I call my service:

```
 id<QRSet> qrSet = [self.proxy doPaginatedList:token :filter :startingIndex];
```

This however is where I am stuck, if I make my method call to return the QRSet, I still only get an NSDictionary object.  Does anyone know what steps I am missing to get it to recreate the QRSet object on the client side?

Comment: The problem might be that you add a translation for `QueryResultSet`, but expect a result of `QRSet`. Is it a type in the question, or a type in your project?

Comment: QRSet was just the text I was using for this question, (it is actually QueryResultSet everywhere in the actual code.)  I fixed it in my question for clarity though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects that are returned from the service, you need to specify the mapping in the CWHessianUnarchiver, like this:

```
[CWHessianUnarchiver setProtocol:@protocol(QRSet) forClassName:@"com.test.queries.QRSet"];
```